# Hyperref doesn't work in TOC

Tags: hyperref

I'm using Hyperref in DVI>PS>PDF compile, but it doesn't work in TOC. I need help. Thanks for your comments.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,letterpaper,spanish]{book}
%----------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[font=small,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{colortbl,enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.59cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{shadowtext} %Paquete Sombras
\usepackage{type1cm} % Paquete tamaño de fuente
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos, textwidth=2cm, shadow,textsize=scriptsize]{todonotes}
\usepackage[skins,most,many,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper,verbose,
tmargin=2.5cm,
bmargin=2cm,
lmargin=4cm,
rmargin=2cm
}
\usepackage[perpage,ragged]{footmisc}
\usepackage{perpage} %the perpage package
\MakePerPage{footnote} %the perpage package command
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}% adds dot after chapter title in ToC
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}% adds leader dots from chapter titles to page numbers
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}% adds dot after section title in ToC
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\tt\color{black},
    literate=%
    {é}{{\'{e}}}1
    {á}{{\'{a}}}1
    {ó}{{\'{o}}}1
    {ú}{{\'{u}}}1
    {í}{{\'{i}}}1,
}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}
\sisetup{group-digits = integer}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits = 4}
\sisetup{group-separator = {.}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{varwidth}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{%
    % #1: label (e.g. "Table 1")
    % #2: separator (e.g. ": ")
    % #3: caption text
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}%
        \centering
        #1#2#3%
    \end{varwidth}%
}
%\usepackage{showframe}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linktoc=all,
    linktocpage=true,
    citecolor=blue,
    breaklinks=true,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}
\usepackage[anythingbreaks]{breakurl}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{azulo}{RGB}{0,163,243}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi welcome ... you've only included your preamble. could you please supply a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading `hyperref` with options

```
linktoc=all,
linktocpage=true,
```

the second one says to put a link *only* in the page number listed in the TOC, and it overrides the former one which instructed to put a link *also* in the page number. I guess this is the problem here.

---

Well, I tested minimal document with the preamble you posted and as expected it produces links in the page numbers, which are coloured:

[image]

contrarily to the screenshot you posted.

There must be some other customization done (for example yours has Contenido, not Índice general).